# Show Open vs Done statistics in YouTrack with custom Workflow States

Tags: report, workflow, youtrack

I'm experimenting with YouTrack 6.5 and I want to output bi-directional **Reported vs. Resolved** diagram [like in Youtrack Help Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBtAS.png).

When I try to plot the diagram I can see reported tickets but completed tickets are missing.

As far as I understand, tickets states should have particular values like **New**, **Resolved**, or **Reopen**. But what if tickets have other possible values: (**Open**, **Done**) instead of (**New** and **Resolved**) in our working process?

Is there a way to map these states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that State values that are supposed to be resolved (Done and others) are marked as Resolved (Project -> target project -> Edit -> Fields -> State -> Done, check Resolved option).

Comment: Does YouTrack counts number of Resolved issues each time when State changes to status with `Resolved` option or it counts number of completed issues at the moment of plot calculation?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The report shows the number of issues of each state (Resolved or New/Reopned) for each day/week/month/year.
For example, on June 5th there were 10 resolved issues and 5 new. On June 6th there were 5 resolved and 5 new.